# Using implode() to separate an array and then use that in an SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, arrays, implode

I am trying to get values from an array that is stored in a column in my database. I have this code so far:

```
<?php $disciplines = (json_decode($traveler['disciplines'])); ?>
<?php $disciplinename = implode(' OR id = ',$disciplines); ?>
<?php $name = "SELECT * from the_discipline WHERE (id = 86 OR id = 118)";
$dname = $obj->queryResult($name);
```

Everything works fine up to a point. I am able to get the array that looks like this in the database "["86", "118"]" and print it out to look like this "86 OR id = 118" (that is the $disciplinename variable) I am then trying to put it in an SQL statement that looks like this "SELECT * from the_discipline WHERE (id = ".$disciplinename.")";. When I do that statement my page won't load and if I type out the statement without the variable like so "SELECT * from the_discipline WHERE (id = "86 OR id = 118")"; it works fine. I have rearranged things and tried many variations of the above code but I can't get anything to work properly. Is there something I'm missing or don't know about using implode() with SQL? Any input or pointers would be much appreaciated.

EDIT*

I have also tried this as suggested below:

```
<?php $disciplines = (json_decode($traveler['disciplines'])); ?>
<?php $disciplinename = implode(', ',$disciplines); ?>
<?php $name = "SELECT * from the_discipline WHERE id IN (".$disciplinename.")"; 
$dname = $obj->queryResult($name);
?>
```

Comment: better use ```.. WHERE id IN (..comma-separated-list..);```

Comment: @ИгорьТыра good idea but that isn't working either. Nothing loads still unfortunately.

Comment: did you change the line with ```implode``` too?

Comment: @ИгорьТыра I believe I changed it correctly but I showed what I did above just in case.

Comment: just look into apache logs to see the actual script error.. it may be something about database connection.

Comment: and more: while using ```json_decode``` use it as ```json_decode(somejson, TRUE)``` to get output actually as array, now it is an object and implode-result may be strange

Comment: What does `var_dump($disciplines)` output?

Comment: @fyrye you saved me with your suggestion of doing "$disciplinename = '"' . implode('", "', $disciplines) . '"';". That worked perfectly thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @ProfessionallyInept You're welcome, was thinking `json_decode()` may be returning an array of objects. like `[ { "id": 1 }, { "id": 2 } ]`, in which case you would use `implode('", "', array_column($disciplines, 'id'));`

Comment: @fyrye good to know for future reference. If you wanna make an answer with the above code I will gladly accept it as the correct way to go.